# IF statement in an Access Form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013, ms-access-forms

I have a table that has 3 fields called Period, Start and End.
I need to make an IF statement (I think) so when I select the Period in a form Combobox then it will fill in the Start And End Boxes with the records from the table.
Something like this

```
IF PComboBox = tblPeriod.Period then StartBox = tblPeriod.Start AND EndBox = tblPeriod.End
```

I know that is wrong, but hopefully it helps you understand what I'm trying to create. Also where would I put this code, in a public function or in a query. I'm not too great with access.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pull all three columns from your table into your combo box and simply hide the 2nd & 3rd columns. (Set the column widths to 3;0;0)

You can now refer to those hidden columns in VBA using Me.PComboBox.Column(1) and Me.PComboBox.Column(2), (Column numbering starts at 0)

So add some code to the after update event of your PComboBox that sets the values something like;

```
Me.StartBox = Me.PComboBox.Column(1)
Me.EndBox = Me.PComboBox.Column(2)
```